# Auto 'form' fill using python

Tags: python, urllib2

Let's say there's a website "http://www.ipuresult.com/" , and I want to submit  roll number say '06051202712'  so that i can view other pages/submit request successfully. How to do that ?

Luckily there's only one 'form' in this site but what if we have much complex html and multiple 'form''s ?

I tried ->

```
>>>form_data={'Roll_No':'01751202712'}

>>>params=urllib.urlencode(form_data)

>>>response=urllib2.urlopen(url,params)

>>>response=url2.urlopen(url,params)

>>>data=response.read()
```

But it didn't worked.

What are the key points to look after ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is what i did ->

roll = '05951202712'

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'Roll_No' : (roll)})
opener.open('http://www.ipuresult.com/index.php', login_data)

stu_marks_raw = opener.open('http://www.ipuresult.com/student_marks.php').read()